# Why does my snow in summer look terrible after flowering

Tags: perennials

Snow in summer looking bad after flowering. Does it need to be cut back

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.